# Estimate stroke width from image

Tags: python, image, algorithm, opencv

I have been working on handwriting recognition, I am thinking of an approach where if I get to know the average thickness of the marker used (pixels used), I will be able to segment characters from word with much better accuracy.

For the picture given below, is there any way where I can estimate the thickness of the pen/marker stroke i.e. the pixels in the image for one stroke of pen.

[image]

Comment: Have you googled: "stroke width transform"?

Comment: @Miki Yeah I have found it, reading the paper You can add that as an answer. Thanks